# how to mock a database query response in rspec for testing other methods depending on the response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, mocking

I have a method in my rails app which is performing some complex queries and returning data.

I have other methods which have specific ways of modelling the returned data from the first.

I need to write RSpec tests for the other methods... and I need to pass in the result from the first method(because execution depends on this data)

How can I mock a response from the database query to use as input in testing my other methods without having to create all the associated records and calling the first method to return the needed data?

**First querying method:**

```
def agents_tasks_performed_this_week_or_assigned(kind = 1)

  condition = "..."
  values = {...}

  User.find(officer_id).supervised_users.active.joins(tasks: :ticket_subject)
    .where(condition, values)
    .select("users.id as agent_id, concat(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) as agent_name, date(tasks.completed_at) as completed_at, tasks.status, tasks.assigned_at")
end
```

**Method to test:**

```
def group_by_kind_and_date(supervisor_id = officer_id, tasks = []) # tasks is a result of the above method.
  district_tasks = {}

  tasks.each do |task|

    unless district_tasks[task.agent_id.to_s]
      district_tasks[task.agent_id] = new_rider_task_hash # this is a new hash of attributes
      district_tasks[task.agent_id][:id] = task.agent_id
    end

    if district_tasks[task.agent_id][:name].nil?
      district_tasks[task.agent_id][:name] = task.agent_name
    end

    ...

  district_tasks.values.sort_by{|item| item[:name].downcase }
end
```

**RSpec test:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe <Module_name> do

  let(:class_instance) { (Class.new {
    include <Module_name>
  }).new }

  describe "#group_by_kind_and_date" do

    it "should not include officers more than once in the response" do
      returned_ids = class_instance.group_by_kind_and_date(@supervisor.id, <...need to pass in tasks mock here...>).map{ |d| d[:id]}
      expect(returned_ids - returned_ids.uniq).to be_empty
    end
  end

end
```

So... I need to get something like an array of mock objects that will have all the returned attributes.

E.g: If returned values are `tasks`, a mock task will have following attributes:

```
task.agent_id, task.agent_name, task.completed_at, task.status and task.assigned_at
```

> Note. A Task instance does not have all these above attributes... these attributes are available because of the `.select` returned values from the query.

Thanks all for all contributions.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to test both this method and the other methods at the same time... when you probably just need to test each independently... but I can't be sure, because you haven't included an example of the spec that you're trying to write (even if it isn't working), and an example of the code and spec for one of the "other methods". ie - it's really hard for us to debug a verbal description of your code :) Please edit your question and add all the relevant sections of code :)

Comment: Thank you @TarynEast I have added snippets from the code examples. I am trying to test these methods independently. How can I mock the returned `tasks` from the first method, so that I can use it as an input for the second method(which I am actually interested in testing)

Comment: My first impression is that your method is really long and probably needs to be split up into smaller methods. Try making your methods no more than 3-4 lines long. If it's bigger - then split into other methods. eg everything inside the "tasks.each do" should be one method (pass in the individual task and the "district tasks" as params and get back out the update version of "district_tasks"). Also take out the ordering-by section into another method that takes "district_tasks" as an arg and passes out the ordered set.

Comment: Then you have less to test - you can just test that the first (data-wrangling) method takes *one* task and preps it right. Then you can test the ordering-method independently of the data-wrangling method. Then you can test that the overall method runs that method once for each task, and then calls the ordering method...

Comment: But to your specific question... you can just set up a let with doubles eg `let(:tasks) { [double(:agent_id => '007', :agent_name => "Bond", :completed_at => 1.day.ago, :status => 'great', :assigned_at => 1.day.ago), double(:agent_id => '99', :agent_name => "99", :completed_at => 2.days.ago, :status => 'in the cold', :assigned_at => 1.day.ago)] }` then pass that in as a variable (I'll move this to an answer if it works ;) )

Comment: Yes, thanks. +100. It worked well.

Comment: cool! I'll make it an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first impression is that your method is really long and probably needs to be split up into smaller methods. Try making your methods no more than 3-4 lines long. If it's bigger - then split into other methods. eg everything inside the "tasks.each do" should be one method (pass in the individual task and the "district tasks" as params and get back out the update version of "district_tasks"). Also take out the ordering-by section into another method that takes "district_tasks" as an arg and passes out the ordered set.

Then you have less to test - you can just test that the first (data-wrangling) method takes one task and preps it right. Then you can test the ordering-method independently of the data-wrangling method. Then you can test that the overall method runs that method once for each task, and then calls the ordering method...

But to your specific question... you can just set up a let with doubles eg

```
let(:tasks) { [
  double(:agent_id => '007', :agent_name => "Bond", :completed_at => 1.day.ago, :status => 'great', :assigned_at => 1.day.ago),
  double(:agent_id => '99', :agent_name => "99", :completed_at => 2.days.ago, :status => 'in the cold', :assigned_at => 1.day.ago)
] }
```

then use that as the second argument.

With the double, you can pass a hash of keys/values that will represent the "methods" the double will respond-to and the value that come from trying that method.

eg the task example above will respond like this:

```
tasks[0].agent_id # => '007'
```

if you need to add different methods,likewise just add the keys/values into the hash that you need and you're good to go :)